# Time series and probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, time-series

I have many mis-conception about time series, random process and random variable.

Sorry for asking similar questions.

There is a time series having infinitely many samples,

such as, $x_1$, $x_2$, ... $x_n$, ...

When I make a histogram of it,

I find the ratio is $0.4$, (the number of sample, larger than $4$)/(the total sample number)

**In this case, 
can I say "the probability that sample is larger than 4 is $0.4$ in this time series, or discrete time random process?"**

Is it right? If it is right, how can I express this probability by using the term of random process, or time series?

I really thank you for reading.

Comment: This would be true if observations were independent form each other, which may or may not be the case. Also, how can you get a histogram of an infinitely-long tim series?

Comment: A random process, is basically an infinite number of random variables with time changing statistics and every random process has such an interpretation. so when you are taking samples, you are assuming that the statistics of all the samples are the same, which means they all have the same distribution and the same hyper parameters that govern that distribution, while this assumption should not be necessarily true, for example temperature of weather at different hours could be a Gaussian with different mean, even worse, some hours could be Laplace distribution.

Comment: What you are doing is basically treating samples as I.I.D. samples from a distribution, while in stochastic process in general term speaking, sample of different times might have different distributions. In other words when samples come from a process, they have time relationship (for example samples that are close in time like two consecutive sample, are more probable to have close values to each other) but when samples are drawn I.I.D. , order is meaningless. Other way to interpret, drawing samples I.I.D. means a discrete stochastic process when all statistics (PDF) are not function of time.

Comment: Why not just say "the fraction of samples that are larger than 4 is $0.4$"  ? [and likely add the detail "considering the $n$ points sampled."]

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I read your comment carefully. You said when the process is i.i.d process, getting the question's probability(ratio) is easily done, right? But, how about only identically distributed, not independent case? In this case, the samples from random process may have some tendencies. In this case, could I get the formula about the ratio, or the probability? I deeply appreciate your detailed comments.

Comment: @David I imagine the case such as estimating the downloading rates of my computer,continuously. In computer network, the samples from observations are not independent but identically distributed. It is called "Gaussian traffic modeling"

Comment: @Michael Thank you. Your expression is more precise at my needs. Is there any hint to express the fraction in terms of the probability of the process?

Comment: @nimdrak : Your description of the system does not prepare you to make a statement about probabilities. Nevertheless, even if you had specified a clear probability model, there is nothing wrong with talking about the _event_ $B$ that the fraction of the first $100$ samples that are larger than 4 is $0.4$: $$B=\left\{\frac{1}{100}\sum_{n=1}^{100} 1_{\{X_n>4\}} = 0.4 \right\}$$ where $1_A$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $A$ is true, and zero else. So $B$ is just an event that you can observe as being true or false.

Comment: @Michael I really appreciate you. Then if assuming $x1, x2, ... xn$ are from $X1,X2 ... Xn $~ $N(mu,sigma)$ with identically distributed but not independent, could I make a statement about probability?

Comment: @Michael You’re very awesome. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for delay, been out for a week. No, the independence is a crucial assumption in defining that probability you are seeking. exactly as @Michael said, id you want to find the probability of the event that $P\left( x(1) \le a , x(2) \le a , ... , x(n) \le a \right)$, then this probability can not be factored into $P\left( x(1) \le a \right) \times P\left( x(2) \le a \right) \times ... \times P\left( x(n) \le a \right)$ unless the independency is guaranteed. If you are certain that they are not independent, still you can investigate for other assumptions like "Independent increments".

Comment: Also you can use Bayes theorem and break the above expression into conditional probabilities and then to discard some interdependency, use Markov assumption, for example only two consecutive values are dependent and other than that are independent. It all is about your problem and which assumption you can force on the problem but still get the reasonable approximate results.